# Yii Ecalendarview extension do not show all dates

Tags: php, events, yii, calendar, yii-extensions

I am using Yii 1.1 and i have integrated Ecalendarview extension to show my events. The problem is that it is showing the date only for upcoming or past events not full month view date. 
[image: Screenshot is here]